# Android Worker PeriodicWorkRequest bug

Tags: android, worker

I try to implement a task launch once every 12 hours. I'm use Android worker for this task.

An interesting bug was discovered in the execution processes.

```sh
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0"
```

```java
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();
        PeriodicWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UrlRequestsService.class,12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Send Data", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,uploadWorkRequest);
```

My Log's - task work's randomly.

```sh
2019-08-21 00:21:14.281 17993-18154/com.app I/UrlRequestsService: doWork
2019-08-21 00:25:12.790 17993-18291/com.app I/UrlRequestsService: doWork
2019-08-21 00:25:13.769 17993-18292/com.app I/UrlRequestsService: doWork
```

Android 9. Device - Galaxy S 10

Comment: Can you share your UrlRequestsService's startWork implementation?